# How to valign a span element in a div

Tags: html, css

I have many span elements within a div. for example:

```
<div>
    <span>element 1 </span>
    <span>element 2 </span>
    <span>element 3 </span>
</div>
```

I would like to vertically align span element 2 so that it will be 50px higher  than the other two. How can i do this?

I tried to style that span like this but i did not work:

```
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: top
```

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/3t6ao52q/1/

I would like it look like this:

[image]

Comment: show some output visual representation, help us easy understand.

Comment: Do you want to change the actual _height_ of the elements, or simply change their vertical _position_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`vertical-align`** property on first and third **`<span>`**,

#### View this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3t6ao52q/9/)</kbd>

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
}
span{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
span:nth-child(1), 
span:nth-child(3) {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try making a class like:

```
.element {
    position:relative; 
    top: +50px;
}

<div>
<span class="element">element 1 </span>
<span>element 2 </span>
<span class ="element">element 3 </span>
```

Comment: For some reason the closing div isn't showing up... don't forget it